# I want to minimise a function with multiple variable

Tags: maxima-minima

$y = \sqrt((x -16)^2 + (x - 6)^2) + \sqrt((x - q)^2 + (x- (-q +10))^2) + \sqrt((q + 7)^2 + ((-q+10) -13)^2)$

where ${x >= 10}$

${x<=20}$

${q>=-10}$

${q <= 0}$

${-q + 10 >= 10}$

${-q +10 <= 20}$

I know how to minimise a function with 1 variable.
I know derivatives/intergrals

For more information the function is the distance between two points passing 
through two lines. In future I would like to add more lines.

Comment: You would take what are called partial derivatives of the function with respect to $x$ and $q$. Then you'd set both of these equal to zero in the same way as in 1D. After that, you should solve to find the $(x,q)$ which make it equal zero.

This is your minima, unless it is just a local minimum. Also check the end points to see if they are lower.

Comment: If I add more lines it wont work ?

Comment: **Welcome to the site !** Would you mind to fix the edit of the expression since it is quite difficult to read ? Have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Thanks. By the way, where are you located (I am in Pau) ?